# How to make a jpg logo able to be enlarged without distortion?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

So i have a logo on jpg , how or what can i do to be able to expand it with out distortion and have it on a format that can be used for marketing, like newspaper adds, apparel, etc..

Comment: If you've only got a small jpg, you're out of luck unless you can save a vector version at a bigger size.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a number of options depending on how complex the logo is, how many colours ... etc. That said, you could try the excellent Blow Up by Alien Skin (http://www.alienskin.com/blowup/) which seems to have better algorithms than those inherent in Photoshop. Illustrator has pretty good tracing abilities or you could trace it yourself and then you could use it at any reasonable resolution for print.